# transforming range data to mean in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

Many times the data, such as age is given is ranges. I want to calculate the mean of these ranges. I am able to calculate it but I feel there is more elegant and perhaps faster way.

Here is the working example:

```
age <- c("0-10", "11-20", "21-30", "31-40") # define the age vector in ranges
age_split<-strsplit(age,"-") # gives the list with splits

for(ii in 1:length(age)){
  age[ii] <- mean(as.numeric(unlist(age_split[ii])))
}
print(age)
## [1] "5"    "15.5" "25.5" "35.5"
```

---

Based on suggestions of lmo and akron, here is the code that can be performance tested from various methods:

```
irows = 100000
data1 <- paste0(sample(1:10, irows, replace = TRUE),"-", sample(11:20, irows, replace = TRUE))
data2 <- data1; data3 <- data1; data4 <- data1 # replicated for testing different methods

#--method 1 -- originally proposed
a1<-Sys.time()
age_split<-strsplit(data1,"-")
for(ii in 1:length(data1)){
  data1[ii] <- mean(as.numeric(unlist(age_split[ii])))
}
Sys.time()-a1

# method 2 (lmo suggestion)
a2<-Sys.time()
data2 <- sapply(strsplit(data2, split="-"), function(i) mean(as.numeric(i)))
Sys.time()-a2

# method 3 (cue from akron)
a3<-Sys.time()
age_split_matrix <-do.call(rbind, strsplit(data3,"-"))
class(age_split_matrix) <- "numeric"
data3<-rowMeans(age_split_matrix)
Sys.time()-a3

# method 4 (akron proposed)
a4<-Sys.time()
data4 <-rowMeans(read.table(text=data4, sep = "-"))
Sys.time()-a4

# validating if outputs match
all.equal(as.numeric(data1),data2)
all.equal(as.numeric(data1),data3)
all.equal(as.numeric(data1),data4)
```

When irow = 100K, the time take from method 1 to 4 are: (1) 2.5s (2) 1.4s (3) 0.34s (4) 6.3s. When irow = 1mil, the time was (1) 23s (2) 14s (3) 6s (4) very long. When irow=10mil, the time was (1) 3.9 min (2) 2.9min (3) very long. This makes me conclude that read.table is really slow. Method 3 takes lot of memory.

Comment: Comments about when and whether you'll accept answers don't belong in the question. If you really think it needs to be said, put it down here in the comments. As far as speed goes, it seems doubtful that it would be a concern here, unless people have ages going up very, very high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a one liner with `sapply`:

```
sapply(strsplit(age, split="-"), function(i) mean(as.numeric(i)))
[1]  5.0 15.5 25.5 35.5
```

`strplit` splits the strings on "-" and returns a list which is fed to `sapply` which then takes each list item, converts the vectors to numeric and calculate the means.

Comment: lmo, I have found your one liner to be quite fast compared to the for loop I originally mentioned. Also taking cue from @akrun, I found rowMeans to be even faster. Since I find this as great learning experience, I am providing a complete example where the performance can be tested.

Comment: I have edited my question in which I provided the code to test 4 different methods. They perform differently and it interesting to know various scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

We can do with `rowMeans` after the reading it in a `data.frame` with `read.table`

```
rowMeans(read.table(text=age, sep="-"))
#[1]  5.0 15.5 25.5 35.5
```